# Style of defining React HOC components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, higher-order-functions, higher-order-components

So, in my React app, I see the following pattern for defining HOCs;

```
export function withMyApi() {
  // Extra function wrapper to allow for clear place for configs.  Plus, you can compose multiple HOCs if necessary
  return function(WrappedComponent) {
    class MyApiUrls extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
      }
      render() {
        return <WrappedComponent api={this.api} {...this.props} />;
      }
    }
    return MyApiUrls;
  };
}
```

How does the above work? Is the HIC returning a function component here?
Is the above way intentionally used to be able to compose ?

So specifically, an HOC returns either a class component or a function component. However, with the above pattern, it is not clear as to what is being returned by the HOC.

Comment: This might help you understand the concept of HOC better. (https://toobaali1.medium.com/understanding-higher-order-components-with-react-js-37ea2e7e140d)

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing that out...However, I have a very specific question around the above style/pattern of defining HOC, which is not really answered in that link...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function in your question is an HOF (high-order-function) of name `withMyApi` which returns an **anonymous** function which accepts a component as `WrappedComponent` argument which, when called, returns the "Component" you passed.

Here is the syntax to use this HOF:

```
const MyComponent = withMyApi()(MyOriginalComponent)
```

Yes, you can say that `withMyApi()(MyOriginalComponent)` is *unnecessary* work, it should have just been `withMyApi(MyOriginalComponent)`.

And I agree. So, here are refactored HOCs:

**Option 1**, using a class component as the wrapper:

```
export function withMyApiClass(WrappedComponent) {
  return class MyApiUrls extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props)
      this.api = 'http://www.example.com'
    }
    render() {
      return <WrappedComponent api={this.api} {...this.props} />
    }
  }
}
```

Syntax to use the above HOC: `const Comp1 = withMyApiClass(Comp)`.

**Option 2**, using a function component as the wrapper:

```
export function withMyApiFunction(WrappedComponent) {
  return function MyApiUrls(props) {
    const api = useRef('http://www.example.com')
    return <WrappedComponent api={api.current} {...props} />
  }
}
```

Syntax to use the above HOC: `const Comp1 = withMyApiFunction(Comp)`.

---

**So, why do we need the first form (in question) of `withMyApi` HOF?**

You may need or may not, depending on your requirement. A typical use-case would be to pass some `config` object. An example:

```
export function withMyApi(config) {
  const { secure } = config
  return function (WrappedComponent) {
    class MyApiUrls extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.api = `http${secure ? 's' : ''}://www.example.com`
      }
      render() {
        return <WrappedComponent api={this.api} {...this.props} />
      }
    }
    return MyApiUrls
  }
}
```

Syntax to use the above HOF: `const Comp1 = withMyApi({ secure: false })(Comp)`.

*PS:* If you ever used Redux, you must have seen [connect](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect) HOF which accepts a few arguments, similar to your HOF in question.

So the basic idea behind writing HOFs is - **separating config parameter from the component parameter to allow people to easily use `compose` function when there are multiple HOCs to use**.

---

**Your questions:**

#### How does the above work?

HOC in question is actually *high-order-function*: It returns a function which, when called, returns a component.

#### Is the HOF returning a function component here?

No, It is returning a function. But when we call the *returned* function, it returns a *class component*. See the *option 2*, that returns a function component.

#### Is the above way intentionally used to be able to compose?

Yes, you can use compose utility (from any library like - [Ramdajs](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#compose), [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#flowRight), or [Redux](https://redux.js.org/api/compose)) to create a new "composed HOC" when using multiple HOCs or HOFs. See [Maximizing Composability](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html#convention-maximizing-composability).

---

#### Edit:

#### I don't like HOF. Can I still achieve composition and configuration?

Yes, an example. Let's say we have written below *HOC*:

```
export function withMyApi(WrappedComponent, config) {
  const { secure } = config
  return function MyApiUrls(props) {
    const api = useRef(`http${secure ? 's' : ''}://www.example.com`)
    return <WrappedComponent api={api.current} {...props} />
  }
}
```

How to use it?

```
const Comp1 = withMyApi(Comp, { secure: true })

/* OR, if you want to use more HOCs.
Nested (dirty? Maybe) */
const Comp1 = withRouter(withMyApi(Comp, { secure: true })) 

-----------------------------------------------------------

// But you CAN NOT compose like this:
const composedHOC = compose(
  withRouter,  // a function : OK
  withMyApi(Comp, { secure: false }) // NOT OK. Because is a React Component now.
)
/* It will give error when you will call composedHOC(...) because 
in React, we don't call components using parenthesis i.e. () but 
we invoke then using angle brackets i.e. < />. */

/* After compsing, you CAN NOT do the below otherwise you are going 
to pass `Comp` 2 times to `withMyApi` : Bad/Confusing... :( 
PLUS you will see errors due to calling a React Component using
parenthesis i.e. () as mentioned above. */
const Comp1 = composedHOC(Comp)

-----------------------------------------------------------

// But you can compose like the below:
const composedHOC = compose(
  withRouter, 
  withMyApi
)
const Comp1 = composedHOC(Comp, { secure: false })
/* It will work because it will pass the TWO parameters - "Comp" & 
"{ secure: false }" to LAST (withMyApi) HOC. And the result of that 
will be passed to FIRST HOC (withRouter). */

-----------------------------------------------------------

// But, surprisingly, there will be error when you change the order:
const composedHOC = compose(
  withMyApi, // FIRST
  withRouter // LAST
)
const Comp1 = composedHOC(Comp, { secure: false })
/* Because it will pass the TWO parameters to LAST HOC (withRouter), 
and result of that to FIRST HOC (withMyApi) and So, withMyApi will 
receive ONLY enhanced "Comp" NOT the "{ secure: false }". This is why
using "compose" is buggy for HOCs that acpect config parameters. */

/* Just to remind, this is what a compose function does:
"Composes single-argument functions from right to left. The rightmost 
function can take multiple arguments as it provides the signature for 
the resulting composite function."
compose(f, g, h) is the same as (...args) => f(g(h(...args)))
Means, it pass args to h, and the result to g and then result to f. */
```

#### Ok, I may like HOF. How to do the same using HOF?

```
export function withMyApi(config) {
  const { secure } = config
  return function (WrappedComponent) {
    return function MyApiUrls(props) {
      const api = useRef(`http${secure ? 's' : ''}://www.example.com`)
      return <WrappedComponent api={api.current} {...props} />
    }
  }
}
```

How to use it?

```
const Comp1 = withMyApi({ secure: false })(Comp)

// OR, if you want to use more HOCs
const composedHOC = compose(
  withRouter,
  withMyApi({ secure: false })
)
const Comp1 = composedHOC(Comp) // Looks clean :)
```

#### Conclusion:

1. Don't use `compose` with HOCs if they accept "component" and one or more "config" object. Use nested approach instead.
2. Use nested or the better - `compose` with HOFs and HOCs (as long as HOCs don't accept a config object)
3. It is **best** to write HOFs when you want to accept one/more **config** objects. So that, people can use `compose` with your HOF.

HOF is better / cleaner if you want to support "configuration" through additional parameters to the function.

> This (HOF) form may seem confusing or unnecessary, but it has a useful property. Single-argument HOCs like the one returned by the connect function have the signature Component => Component. Functions whose output type is the same as its input type are really easy to compose together.

Comment: Awesome explanation...So I now clearly understand that is actually a HOF and when we invoke, the returned function is when we actually get back the enhanced class/function component.

Only thing still slightly unclear is regarding composition, it would have been really great if you could have elaborated that further with examples and also, if is not possible to implement composition w/o the wrapper function i.e. if it is implemented and used as withMyApiClass(Comp) OR withMyApiFunction(Comp)

Comment: **Updated** my answer with examples on composition. Earlier I was wrong a bit. Here is corrected line : `Yes, you can use compose utility (from any library like - Ramdajs, Lodash, or Redux) to create a new "composed HOC" when using multiple HOCs or HOFs`

Comment: Your answers are bang on and absolutely what I am looking for...Just last couple of questions;
1. For "compose" function, should it be considered that we can use compose "only" if the return value is a function and not a component ?  (like you have mentioned in your example withMyApi(Comp, { secure: false }) // NOT OK. As it is a React Component now.)
2. What exactly do you mean single-argument HOCs ?

Comment: Just to add, in the above point 1. I meant ......that we can use compose "only" if the return value (of individual arguments passed to compose) is a function ....

Comment: @testndtv Yes. Right. So, it is better to write HOF when you want to pass some parameters (like `config`). So that it can be used in a compose function.

Comment: Sorry, I have accepted the answer now...But slightly confused again...for passing configs, you have showed examples for both (with AND w/o HOF)...So when you say better, I assume HOF is just a preferred way when trying to pass configs?

Also, could you please add on point 2 i.e. What exactly do you mean single-argument HOCs ?

Comment: Sure...Thank you so very much...I'll eagerly wait for your so very helpful comments...If possible, I would have upvoted you 1000 times !

Comment: Oh k...Enjoy your dinner :)

Comment: `What exactly do you mean single-argument HOCs?`: HOCs those accept only 1 parameter i.e. a component and return the enhanced component. If your HOC needs to accept more than 1 parameter, make it HOF for reasons mentioned in my answer.

Comment: I updated my answer. And I hope that Now all of your doubts will be cleared. Let me know if you have more questions.

Comment: `I assume HOF is just a preferred way when trying to pass configs? ` Yes

Comment: I would suggest you to read the full answer again. As I have improved it a lot. And, thanks to your questions as it cleared my understanding too.

Comment: Awesome....yes, you have explained in an extremely detailed fashion....So let me put some time going through each and every point again....While you seemed to have now answered over and above what was expected, I'll get back to you only if the need arises for any further clarification....

Comment: I know you have answered everything in detail and I have been going through your post in detail....It would be really really great if you could just clarify this point you have made....

/* It will give error when you will call composedHOC(...) because 
in React, we don't call components using parenthesis i.e. () but 
we invoke then using angle brackets i.e. < />. */

Comment: It simply means that we render components using `< ... />`, not `()`. Assume a component: `function Welcome() { return <h1>Hello</h1> }`. Then to render the `Welcome` component, we write `<Welcome/>`, not `Welcome()`. And, `composedHOC` is a react component in the mentioned example.

Comment: Thanks again...So I am trying to understand the result of calling compose....Is the result of calling compose() different in the below 2 cases i.e. In first case, we compose function and React component, while in 2nd case, we compose 2 functions;
const composedHOC = compose(
  withRouter, 
  withMyApi(Comp, { secure: false })
)

V/s calling 
const composedHOC = compose(
  withRouter,  
  withMyApi
)

Answer (score 0):

It actually returns a function which you will be using to return a Class Component.

I think the confusion lies with the concept of HOC as the above pattern with a wrapper function.

This pattern allows us to enhance our components without breaking the concept of HOC.

We need to maintain the HOC's concept but we might need to add extra configuration or compose multiple components, the above pattern will be useful.

`Component => Component`

The above becomes:

`WrapperFunction()(Component) => Component`

But we can wonder why not directly pass another args through the HOC:

`HOC(Component, <any extra config we want>)`

The HOC says, it takes a Component and returns a Component and extra args doesn't seems really positive isn't it?